# How to get all tags belonging to the article?

Tags: php, mysql, tags

Please excuse my English. I created a website base on tags, with MVC architecture and PHP. It work fine. When the user clicks on the tag, the query gives all info for that tag. For Example, a user clicks on the "PHP" tag, the query show all articles that have the "PHP" tag. This is my query

```
    public function get($Getlabel){
    $tagLabel = $this->db->prepare("select `txtcenter`.`id`, `title`, `imagurl`, `writer`, `dttime`, `txtmain`, `counter`,
                                              `tags`.`tag` as tagsshow
                                            from `txtcenter`
                                              INNER  join `taglink` on `taglink`.`txtcenterid` = `txtcenter`.`id`
                                              INNER  join `tags` on `tags`.`id` = `taglink`.`tagid`
                                            where `tags`.`tag` in (:Label)
                                            ");
    $tagLabel->execute(array('Label' => $Getlabel));
    return $tagLabel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Lets now explain my problem. I want each article have all tags belongs too in the below with edit above query for it.

Comment: Why Every Word Begins With A Capital Letter ?

Comment: @PHPglue : yes its work .  i say Use MVC And Its Clear !!!!

Comment: Why is it `$this->db->prepare()`? Did you create your own class that has a `$db` property, which has its own `prepare()` method?

Comment: yes i create Tags Class and __construct(PDO $db) Get Data From controller Tag

Comment: my problem in the Query ! Not Php Code , and i thinking mybe use id  Instead tag  (:Label) can any one give me idea ?

Comment: I presume naming `:Label` a variable would cause troubles. Did you try using one without the `:`?

Comment: I *guess* the question aims at getting *all* tags belonging to each post selected by one single tag. There is no error in the above code so poking around `$db` or placeholders is not the right way to go.

Comment: @Alejandro Iván : my mistake your right ,  becouse Edit code Couple Of time Its Happen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a list of the article tags in the query you can use something like this

```
    select tbl.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.tag SEPARATOR ',') As all_tags
from(
select `txtcenter`.`id`, `title`, `imagurl`, `writer`, `dttime`, `txtmain`, `counter`,
`tags`.`tag` as tagsshow, `taglink`.`tagid`
from `txtcenter`
INNER  join `taglink` on `taglink`.`txtcenterid` = `txtcenter`.`id`
INNER  join `tags` on `tags`.`id` = `taglink`.`tagid`
where `tags`.`tag` in (:Label)
) tbl
inner join tags  
on tags.id=tbl.tagid
GROUP BY tbl.id
```

This query should work i haven't run it because i don't have your table.